# Web cam not opening through python cv2 VideoCapture called via php

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, opencv, xampp

I am trying to build a facial recognition web app. I run the image capture and processing code via python scripts, and call the python file from php.

The python code works when called via command line, but through php, the **cam.read()** simply does not capture any frames, and the **return value is always false**. I do get the **cam.isOpened()** **value to be true** though, hence I know that my camera is turned on. It's just that it isn't reading any frames when called via php.

Also, the read() function returns true when I read the frames from a video file rather than the webcam.

Any help on figuring out why would be appreciated! Could it be related to xampp permissions or so? I'm running the **xampp server on macOS**.

Here's my code:

## test.py

```
import cv2
import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #initialize webcam
time.sleep(2) #to warm up camera sensor

retL = [] #to store the frame return values

i = 0
while i < 10:
    ret, frame = cam.read() #read frames from webcam
    retL.append(ret)
    i += 1

cam.release()
print(retL) #returns a list filled with 'False' only when the script is called from php
```

## test.php

```
 <?php
      $a = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/python3 test.py 2>&1');
      echo $a;
 ?>
```

Comment: run `shell_exec('whoami')` command from within a php script to see what user is used, then try running the script as this user and see if it has the same issues

Comment: @Marcin It says "daemon". How do I run it as this user?

Comment: have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/294736/run-a-shell-script-as-another-user-that-has-no-password

Comment: @Marcin I added daemon to the sudo group on visudo and ran the command, but it's still the same, unfortunately :/